# What Pokemon are unavailable to catch with these games?

Tags: pokemon-series

I have:

- Pokemon Emerald
- Pokemon Diamond
- Pokemon SoulSilver
- Pokemon Black

Which Pokemon will I have to trade for that cannot be caught in any of these games? Are there any choices I have to go with a specific option to avoid getting two of the same legendary?

Comment: The only real trouble is Pokemon Emerald. You can get nearly perfect with HeartGold, White, and Pearl, but Neither Emerald/Sapphire or Emerald/Ruby give you 100% of the 3rd gen pokemon alone. I'm not sure if HeartGold, White, and Pearl can make up for the shortfall, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Can we assume all the pokemon will eventually be transfered to your copy of Black?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, if you're looking at 3rd Generation, the version specific Pokemon that are not present in Emerald are:

- Surskit (Swarm in Diamond)
- Masquerain (evolve Surskit)
- Meditite (Routes 208, 210, 211, others, in Diamond)
- Medicham (evolve Meditite)
- Roselia (Routes 212, 221, 224, 225, others, in Diamond)
- Zangoose (Safari Zone in Soul Silver)
- Lunatone (Safari Zone in Soul Silver)

So you're completely covered in 3rd gen due to your later games, though you *will* have to beat Emerald twice: Once for Latios and once for Latias (Alternatively, buy Ruby *or* Sapphire, and just pick the other Lati@s in Emerald)

The version exclusive Pokemon absent in Diamond are:

- Tangela (Routes 21, 28, and 44, Mt. Silver in Soul Silver)
- Tangrowth (evolve Tangela)
- Pinsir (Safari Zone / National Park Bug-Catching Contest in Emerald / Soul Silver)
- Articuno, Zapdos and Moltres (Available in Soul Silver)
- Slowpoke (Slowpoke Well in Soul Silver)
- Slowbro/ Slowking (evolve Slowpoke)
- Misdreavous (Safari Zone, Cliff Cave, Mt. Silver (Night) in Soul Silver)
- Mismagius (evolve Misdreavous)
- Houndour (Route 7, Safari Zone, Soul Silver)
- Houndoom (evolve Houndour)
- Stantler (Routes 36, 37, Soul Silver)
- Tropius (Route 119, Emerald)
- Spheal (Shoal Cave, Emerald)
- Sealio / Walrein (evolve Spheal)
- Bagon (Meteor Falls, Emerald)
- Shellgon / Salamance (evolve Bagon)
- Regirock / Regice / Registeel (Emerald)
- **Shieldon / Bastiodon** (not obtainable in any of the listed games: Need Pearl / Platinum)
- **Glameow** (not obtainable in the listed games: Need Pearl)
- Rotom (Old Chateau post national-dex, Diamond)

And of course, the White version exclusive Pokemon, which aren't present in the previous generations.

So, you look to be mostly set if you just buy White, as there are only 3 other unobtainable non-event Pokemon. As near as I can determine, buying both Pearl and White will get you all the Pokemon.

Comment: Note that you could conceivably obtain Shieldon, Bastiodon and Glameow via the GTS: you are guaranteed to see all three of them if you fight all of the trainers in Diamond, and that's enough to put up a trade request or search for them. (Of course, there still needs to be someone else willing to make a reasonable trade involving those.) I think it's similar for Black/White, but I haven't even started those properly yet, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Emerald does not have to be beaten twice. In SoulSilver after you retrieve Copycat's lost doll, Latios will start roaming Kanto (Latias in HeartGold), So you just need to ensure that in Emerald you tell your mother it was a red pokemon you saw on the TV to trigger Latias.

Comment: This is also missing Jirachi and Deoxys?

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the White-exclusive Pokemon, obviously, but you can't get Shieldon, Bastiodon, Glameow, Purugly, Palkia(unless you have an event Arceus), Growlithe or Arcanine, or any of the Event Pokemon (Mew, Celebi, Jirachi, Deoxys, Phione, Manaphy, Darkrai, Shaymin, and Arceus), plus you'd only be able to get one of the Generation 3, 4, and 5 starters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could get 2 of the third generation starters because you can get one in Soul Silver after beating Red. Also you can get the other second, third and fourth by starting a new game and migrating them once you have 7 Pokemon which takes about 20 minutes.

However, you would need to beat Soul Silver 3 times to get all the first gen starters unless you get a Fire Red / Leaf Green to migrate from. And I believe you can get Shieldon / Blastidon from the guy at the bottom of Twisted Mountains in Black.

I'm sure by now you have X/Y which is going to become the easiest way to get Pokemon.  There is something like 450 available between them; the most out of any other version and it will let you get the first gen starters. Also thanks to the online Pokemon bank and PC you don't have to worry about the mass amounts of trades needed when you have to restart to get those other starters.